# Rest API and admin in the same application

Tags: rest, codeigniter, api, architecture, restful-architecture

I'm new to building APIs, I made the first one using an MVC framework: codeigniter, with chris kacerguis rest implementation.

I'm not really sure this was the best think to do because I believe maybe the framework is not that "slim" or light just to API's purposes.

I plan to do a mobile App, an admin and a website so the three can consume the Api's services.

Is it a bad idea to have the API, the website and the admin on the same project? which are the pros and cons? or the best architectural approach?

Otherwise I will have: One Codeigniter project for the API and Another Codeigniter project for website and admin

thanks

Comment: Are you using an ORM something like Doctrine?

Answer (score 0):

You can create folders in "controllers" folder to organize your project and use the same project/env configuration :

```
controllers/Home.php  
controllers/api/MyApi.php 
controllers/admin/Admin.php
```

Edit : You will share models and libraries too.

Answer (score 0):

In my project I realized 2 types of controller - REST and API. Admin js gui work with REST, other world work with API. You can do it simply with silex framework, a little brother of symfony.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of building a REST API so that you only have to build one project for your business model. This allows you to construct any number of applications on any platform, only requiring you to consume the API in different ways. This essentially separates/decouples the user interface from the business logic, and vice versa.

You should create separate projects for the REST API and each UI project should also be separated projects. This allows you to change the underlying code, language and platform in any one of the projects without breaking any of the other projects as long as the API signatures remain the same.

For example, you could have a live version of your website built using Codeignitor while developing another septate project using AngularJS. When your AngularJS project is complete you would simply swap out the project on your server (or create an entirely new website or server) still allowing you to use the other if required. Additionally, you may decide that you would like to move the API onto a different platform, language or database, develope it and swap the implementation when finished causing no changes to any of your UI projects assuming you have not changed the API signatures.

Comment: I also wanted to comment that unless your Admin application is significantly different from your client website/app, you should assign Users with a Role and display/request data from the API based on the Users Role.